# check existence of data in python dictionary

Tags: python, validation, dictionary, key

I have a program that maintains a flat file database of cd information.  I am trying to write a function that updates the database.  In this function I am checking to see if the artist exists and if so, appending the album name to this artist, but for some reason it will not see that the artist I type in already exists. I made sure that I type it in exactly like it is in the dictionary but for some reason python will not see that it is there.  Why would this be happening? I have included sample input as well as the python program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys

def add(data, block):
    artist = block[0]
    album = block[1]
    songs = block[2:]
    if artist in data:
        data[artist][album] = songs
    else:
        data[artist] = {album: songs}
    return data


def parseData():

    global data
    file='testdata.txt'
    data = {}
    with open(file) as f:
        block = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == '':
                data = add(data, block)
                block = []
            else:
                block.append(line)
        data = add(data, block)

    return data

def artistQry():

    global artists, usrChoiceArt, albums, usrChoiceAlb, usrArtist

    artists=sorted(data.keys())
    for i in range(0,len(artists)) :
        print str(i+1) + " : " + artists[i]



    usrChoiceArt = raw_input("Please choose an artist or enter q to quit:")

    if usrChoiceArt=='q' :
        print "Quitting Now"
        exit()
    else :
        albumQry()

def albumQry():

    global artists, usrChoiceArt, albums, usrChoiceAlb, usrArtist

    usrArtist=artists[int(usrChoiceArt)-1]
    albums=sorted(data[usrArtist].keys())

    for i in range(0,len(albums)) :
        print str(i+1) + " : " + albums[i]

    usrChoiceAlb=raw_input("Please choose an album or enter a to go back:")

    if usrChoiceAlb=="a":
        artistQry()
    else:
        trackQry()


def trackQry():

    global artists, usrChoiceArt, albums, usrChoiceAlb, usrArtist

    usrAlbum=albums[int(usrChoiceAlb)-1]
    tracks=data[usrArtist][usrAlbum]

    for i in range(0,len(tracks)) :
        print tracks[i]

    usrChoiceTrack=raw_input("Enter \"a\" to go back or \"q\" to quit:")

    if usrChoiceAlb=="q":
        print "Quitting Now"
        exit()
    elif usrChoiceTrack=="a":
        albumQry()
    else:
        print "Invalid Choice"
        trackQry()


def artistExist(Name):

    for i in range(0,len(data.keys())):

        if Name==data.keys()[i]:
            return True
        else:
            return False




def updData():

    artistName=raw_input("Please enter an artist name:")
    albumName=raw_input("Please enter an album name:")
    trackList=raw_input("Please enter the track list seperated by comma's:")

    if artistExist(artistName):
        data[artistName].append(albumName)
        print data[artistName]
    elif not artistExist(artistName):
        print "Quitting"
        exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
data = parseData()


if sys.argv[1]=='-l':
    artistQry()
elif sys.argv[1]=='-a':
    updData()
```

Input data:

```
Bob Dylan
1966 Blonde on Blonde
-Rainy Day Women #12 & 35
-Pledging My Time
-Visions of Johanna
-One of Us Must Know (Sooner or Later)
-I Want You
-Stuck Inside of Mobile with the Memphis Blues Again
-Leopard-Skin Pill-Box Hat
-Just Like a Woman
-Most Likely You Go Your Way (And I'll Go Mine)
-Temporary Like Achilles
-Absolutely Sweet Marie
-4th Time Around
-Obviously 5 Believers
-Sad Eyed Lady of the Lowlands
```

Comment: Is [this account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4959809/user4959809) also yours? I notice you both have a question with the exact same input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `artistExist`, you return False on the very first iteration! Instead, you must wait until all iterations are finished.

```
for i in range(0,len(data.keys())):

    if Name==data.keys()[i]:
        return True
return False
```

---

In addition to what [Padraic Cunningham says below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30699718/478288), the `elif` here is also redundant:

```
if artistExist(artistName):
    ...
elif not artistExist(artistName):
    ...
```

If something isn't True, then it can only be False. So really you should just have

```
if artistExist(artistName):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

And since the function is just a needless one-liner, an even better expression is

```
if artistName in data:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from returning too early by returning False in the loop you are doing way too much work, you simply need to use `return Name in data`:

```
def artistExist(Name):
    return Name in data # will return True or False with O(1) lookup
```

Every time you call `.keys` you are creating a list in python2  so your lookup is actually quadratic in the worst case as opposed to `0(1)` with the simple `return Name in data`. A big part of using a dict is efficient lookups which you lose calling .keys. If you actually wanted to iterate over the keys you would simply `for key in data`, no call to .keys and no need for range.

Comment: Yes, that too. I was kind of confused by why the OP was looping.

Comment: @chrisaycock, yes, there are numerous things I would change, I just picked this as it was painful to look at as it was so inefficient!